# sitecore 8 target not getting set for insert link

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

On Insert link, I have set target window to "new browser". But on click the link opens in current window only. On inspecting page found that target field is not getting set for anchor tag. Where should I check for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

For link to be rendered properly including optional attributes (such as Target, Style, Title, etc.) use provided Sitecore Helper or SiteCore Link renderer.

Try this for MVC/Razor:

`@Html.Sitecore().Field("Link Field")`

or this if you are using WebForms:

`<sc:link field="Link Field" />`

For example, the following will NOT work as it's not explicitly setting target, etc.

```
Sitecore.Data.Fields.LinkField linkField = item.Fields["Link1"];
var linkSrc = linkfield.GetFriendlyUrl();
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks to be a known bug. 
Few people wrote about this bug: 
https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2015/08/26/general-link-field-bug-with-internal-links-opening-in-new-window/

http://www.bugdebugzone.com/2015/06/sitecore-8-general-link-field-target_23.html

http://blog.horizontalintegration.com/2015/06/20/sitecore-8-general-link-field-internal-link-target-doesnt-render-properly/

Comment: I encountered same issue while inserting media link. Already tried all the above options suggested by you in above three links. I am using Sitecore 8 rev 150812. Can somebody confirm if it's an open sitecore bug?